# automatic telnet version check with CMD window

Tags: windows, cmd, telnet

I need to check telnet version of 6 computers simultaneously.
I was able to open cmd windows and telnet for each 6 computer.

```
@echooff
echo version check for XXX:
telnet [IP] [PORT]
```

but I want to open the window using **telnet ver** cmd so it will display the version automatically from the start

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you explain more specifically what you want to do? Do you require a program to get version information automatically using TELENET? or BAT file?

Comment: Some have suggested using SendKey to telnet. https://serverfault.com/questions/41919/can-the-windows-telnet-client-be-scripted

Comment: I'm trying to use a one BAT file for all 6 computers